# Assigning data to a PageModel property in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have this property in my `PageModel`:

```
public List<string> PhonenumbersFromExcel { get; set; }
```

I want to show data imported from Excel in my view. How can I assign my data in order to show from controller.

My question is: How can I do this? and is there any other way to solve it?

Below you can see my controller:

```cs
public virtual async Task<IActionResult> ImportPhonenumbersFromExcel(Model model, IFormFile importexcelfile, int currentFestivalId)
{
    var phonenumbersFromExcel = new List<string>();

    try
    {
        if (importexcelfile != null && importexcelfile.Length > 0)
        {
            var result = await _importManager.ImportPhonenumbersFromXlsxAsync(importexcelfile.OpenReadStream());

            foreach (var item in result.Distinct())
            {
                var validPhonenumber = "";

                // ensure given phonenumber starts with 0
                if (!item.StartsWith("0"))
                {                       
                    string zeroAdded = "0" + item;
                    validPhonenumber += zeroAdded;
                }

                bool isValid = true;

                if (!CommonHelper.IsValidMobile(validPhonenumber))
                    isValid = false;

                if (!CommonHelper.IsValidPhoneNumber(validPhonenumber))
                    isValid = false;

                if (isValid)
                    phonenumbersFromExcel.Add(validPhonenumber);
            }

            model.PhonenumbersFromExcel.AddRange(phonenumbersFromExcel);
        }

        _notificationService.SuccessNotification(await _localizationService.GetResourceAsync("Admin.Festival.Phonenumbers.Imported"));

        return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = currentFestivalId });
    }
    catch (Exception em)
    {
        await _notificationService.ErrorNotificationAsync(em);
        return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = currentFestivalId });
    }
}
```

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0) might help

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to read data from Excel and display it on the page? You can use `ExcelDataReader`.

I did a simple test, you can refer to it.

Install related Nuget packages: `ExcelDataReader` and `System.Text.Encoding.CodePages`.

Model:

```
public class Phonenumber
{
    public List<string> PhonenumbersFromExcel { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class PhonenumberController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index(Phonenumber phonenumber = null)
    {
        phonenumber = phonenumber == null? new Phonenumber() : phonenumber;
        return View(phonenumber);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(IFormFile excelFile, [FromServices] IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        //I created a folder called files under wwwroot
        string fileName = $"{hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath}\\files\\{excelFile.FileName}";
        using (FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(fileName))
        {
            excelFile.CopyTo(fileStream);
            fileStream.Flush();
        }
        var phoneNumber = this.GetNumber(excelFile.FileName);
        return View(phoneNumber);
    }

    private Phonenumber GetNumber(string fName)
    {
        Phonenumber phonenumberModel = new Phonenumber();
        phonenumberModel.PhonenumbersFromExcel = new List<string>();
        var fileName = $"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}{@"\wwwroot\files"}" + "\\" + fName;
        System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
        using (var stream = System.IO.File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    phonenumberModel.PhonenumbersFromExcel.Add(reader.GetValue(0).ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        return phonenumberModel;
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model Project.Models.Phonenumber

<div>
    <form asp-action="Index" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="excelFile" />
        <input type="submit" value="Import" />
    </form>

    @if (Model.PhonenumbersFromExcel !=null &&Model.PhonenumbersFromExcel.Count()>0)
    {
        <hr />
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" class="table">
            @foreach (var phonenumber in Model.PhonenumbersFromExcel)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@phonenumber</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    }
</div>
```

Test Result:

[image]